# Change Registry Value for Trident

Tags: windows, registry, user-agent

Inside the Windows registry is the following:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\5.0\User Agent

Right now I have the following values:

```
Name:(Default)  
Type: REG_SZ
Value: Application Value

Name:Compatible 
Type: REG_SZ
Value: compatible Value

Name:Version
Type: REG_SZ
Value: Version Value

Name:Platform
Type: REG_SZ
Value: Platform Value
```

This gets me the output from `whatsmyuseragent.com`

> Application value (compatible value;
>   Version value; Platform value;
>   Trident/5.0)

My question is what and where is the value of Trident/5.0 stored at?

I have a bat script I used to change the current values for testing our server.

But have no clue after using different programs to search for that value in the registry.

Any suggestions to where and how to change that value in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to change the `User-Agent` header by changing settings in the Registry.

To answer the question: it is not in the registry anywhere.